# Jackson Serialize / deserialize empty values

Tags: java, jackson

I want to serialize an object to JSON and ignore empty fields. for that I used

```
objectMapper
 .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
 .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY)
```

now I want the opposite way. 
to be able to deserialize it back to object but without null but empty values.
using the mapper object.

I don't want to touch the class itself and I want it to work for any kind of class (to be generic).
is it possible?

Thanks.